# Prove that there exist intervals in $\left[0,\infty \right)$ on which $f_n \to f$ uniformly and on which $f_n \not \to f$ uniformly

Tags: real-analysis

Consider the sequence of functions $f_n: \left[0,\infty \right) \to \mathbb{R}$, which $f_n(x) = \frac{x^{n}}{x^n+1}$.

Prove that there exists an interval in $\left[0,\infty \right)$ on which $f_n \to f$ uniformly and there exists an interval in $\left[0,\infty \right)$ on which $f_n \not\to f$ uniformly.

I find some hardship to find some specific interval.

I have proved that $f_n$ converges to $$f = \begin{cases} 0&,0\le x< 1\\1/2 &, x =1\\1 &, x>1 \end{cases}$$

Comment: The same question was posted a few minutes ago... Where does it come from ? please provide some context, and your work so far...

Comment: I deleted that question since I have done the pointwise proof part. But for the intervals, I really have no clue right now.

Comment: 'I have no clue' is not true. You must have tried some things. For instance, you know the definition of uniform convergence, have you tried writing it down and seeing what it gives for the current function ?

Comment: What is the pointwise convergence of this sequence?

Comment: @ɧɿρρԹʅȝՇԵՐՎԾՌ I edited it. I screwed up the cases.

Answer (score 0):

We see $f_n \to f$ uniformly on $[0, 1/2]$, for $$\sup_{0 \le x \le 1/2}|f_n(x) - f(x)| = \sup_{0 \le x \le 1/2} \frac{x^n}{1 + x^n} \le \sup_{0 \le x \le 1/2} x^n = \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^n \to 0$$

However, $f_n$ does not converge uniformly to $f$ on $(1, \infty)$:

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \sup_{x > 1} |f_n(x) - f(x)| = \lim_{n\to \infty} \sup_{x > 1} \frac{1}{1 + x^n} = \lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{1}{2} = \frac{1}{2} \neq 0.$$

Answer (score 0):

Ok so for $x>1$, $f_n(x)\to1$.

We can prove that for $x<.5$, it's uniformly convergent :

$\sup_{x<.5}|f_n(x)-f(x)|=\sup_{x<.5}\frac{x^n}{x^n+1}\le\frac{1}{1+2^n}\to_{n\infty}0$

Now let's find an interval on which it is not :

$\sup_{x>1}|f_n(x)-f(x)|=\sup_{x>1}|\frac{1}{x^n+1}|=\frac{1}2\neq0$, hence on $(1,\infty)$ it's only simply convergent.

Comment: So the answer is about the codomain? Why do you say $x<.5$ instead of $0<x<1$? Shouldn't we try to find the interval in the domain?

Comment: @bestannie I meant $0<x<.5$. Since we were working on positive numbers, I didn't find it necessary to write the $0<$